# Redirect user if the referrer is not PayPal related

Tags: paypal

I have created a page:

`http://mypage.com/paypal`

with a custom template that contains the code to grab the ipn response from paypal etc.

Now, I need to redirect users accidentally or on a purpose access

`http://mypage.com/paypal`

I want to allow that to only when a user is redirected from paypal url. e.g. if it contains `http://paypal.com`or `https://paypal.com` then it's ok, but all other access redirect to WP homepage.

How to do that?

Comment: You would want to look at the response from paypal https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/#example_req_resp check for the expected information. This isn't really related to WordPress you might be better asking this on stackoverflow.

Comment: @MarkDavidson Mark, I am asking for a WP build-in function or best practice to redirect a user if the referrer is not `http://paypal.com...something....` Is it clearer now?

Comment: Referrer can be spoofed very easily you'd really want to check the information provided in the response.In terms of redirect you would want to use `wp_redirect` http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect if you did want to check the referer I'm not aware of a WordPress native method to do this so you'd probably need to write something yourself. Using something like `parse_url($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Answer (score 1):

What you do is you pass an argument to the Paypal's return URL.  For example:

So your return URL may look like this:

```
$url = home_url();
$url = add_query_arg( array( 'paypal' => '8832002472223abc' ), $url );

$paypal_ipn = array(
     'return_url' => $url
     // rest of your ipn data
)
```

In your IPN template, you can have something like this:

```
if ( ! isset( $_GET['paypal'] ) || $_GET['paypal'] !== '8832002472223abc' ) {
    $url = home_url();
    wp_safe_redirect( $url );
    exit;
}
```

So with that code, when anyone goes to your IPN template page will be redirected unless they have that key=>value combination.